# scrollIntoView Not maintaining position after scrolling is finished

Tags: javascript, html

the problem is as follows:
I have a function that runs on `<body onload="init();"`,
next, I have the init function:

```
function init() {

            id = window.location.href.split('#!')[1];
            console.log(id)
            document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView({
                behavior: "auto",
                block: "center",
                inline: "center"
            });

        }
```

The id is correct and working. The wanted behavior is for the page to scroll to the element with the `id`
What actually happens is the document scroll as expected to the element `id`, but then it jumps back to the original position the page was in before I refreshed it.

Can you help me remove this jump to the original position?

Thanks

Comment: [scroll-snap-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-align) can fix your problem

Comment: Hey, are you suggesting I do scroll-snap-align none on the body?

Comment: Tried multiple things with scroll-snap-align, didn't work